# How to edit a PyCharm macro?

Tags: xml, macros, ide, pycharm

Is it possible to edit (add / change) PyCharm macros?

**Context:**

The GUI 'Edit Macro' option (below) allows macro actions to be removed or renamed, *but not added or edited*.
[image: Edit Macros window]

**Attempted Solution:**

If you record a macro in PyCharm, it is stored in a config folder as `macros.xml` when PyCharm closes.

```xml
<application>
  <component name="ActionMacroManager">
    <macro name="Example Macro">
      <typing text-keycode="77:1;89:0">My</typing>
      <action id="EditorEnter" />
      <typing text-keycode="69:1;88:0;65:0;77:0;80:0;76:0;69:0">Example</typing>
      <action id="EditorEnter" />
      <typing text-keycode="77:1;65:0;67:0;82:0;79:0">Macro</typing>
    </macro>
  </component>
</application>
```

If you close PyCharm, edit the XML file, then PyCharm will subsequently notice the changes on start up ... and reject them:

[image: Application Files Changed window]

Curses!

Logically the state must be stored somewhere else so that it can be reloaded/reset on start-up.

Does anyone know if it is possible to make the edited XML changes apply? If there's any option to edit the state, or force loading of the XML then it would be a super-useful way to edit and share macro files...

I've Googled and FAQ'ed my way around the internet with no success - at this point any pointers or suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: I submitted your question to pycharm support. Let's see if they bite...

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I've submitted a very closely related question to them, but no movement yet. Fingers crossed for answers to both!

Comment: Hello! We have related issues in YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-81162, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-92246. Feel free to vote for them and leave comments.

Comment: y.bedrov - thank you for the links. I have commented and voted on those issues, and will link any news. Those issues have been around since 2012 and there hasn't been any resolution yet. Until PyCharm gets some new features, a work around would still be very useful...